# What is the equivalent scala type for TypeScript Type<any>

Tags: angular, scala.js

I am using a TypeScript library (angular) that has a function which takes a Type as a parameter:

```
ComponentFactoryResolover.resolveComponent(component: Type<any>)
```

But I don't know how I should define this in my scala code. Specifically, what is the corresponding scala type for Type[any] if there even is one:

```
@js.native
@JSImport("@angular/core","ComponentFactoryResolver")
class ComponentFactoryResolver extends js.Object {
    def resolveComponentFactory(component: ???): Unit = js.native
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing TypeScript with JavaScript.

Comment: No. Scala.js also works for TypeScript

Comment: `Type<any>` declares a constructor function for a given type. So how would you define a type in Scala as `Function`?

Answer (score 0):

Scala.js does not have a very specific type for run-time class values (or constructor functions). Since the actual value we would pass to such an argument would typically be the result of calling `js.constructorOf[Foo]` for some `Foo`, which returns a `js.Dynamic`, I would recommend to translate TypeScript's `Type<T>` into `js.Dynamic` in Scala.js.